# Error al desplegar App En Websphere Liberty

Tags: java, linux, oracle, bash, websphere

estoy intentando desplegar una aplicación básica que muestre una consulta usando Oracle, en Websphere Liberty en Linux con java, los paso que he hecho son:

1. Descargar WAS Liberty para Linux
2. Extraer la carpeta llamada wlp
3. Crear un servidor usando la consola de linux
4. Dentro de la carpeta wlp/usr se creó una carpeta con  el nombre del servidor
5. Dentro de carpeta wlp/usr/nuevoservidor/app/ importé el archivo .ear, aquí la clase que hice para la prueba:

   public class PruebaWas {

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Statement statement = null;
       Connection conexion = null;
       String CONSULTA = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTE"; 
       try {
           InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
           DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/oracle");
           conexion = dataSource.getConnection();
           // Ejecutar consulta
           ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(CONSULTA);
           rs.next();
           // Mostrar datos
           System.out.println("******************************************************************");
           System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + "\t" + rs.getString(2) + "\t" + rs.getString(3));
           System.out.println("******************************************************************");
       } catch (NamingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           try {
               conexion.close();
           } catch (SQLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Hay un archivo server.xml que se debe editar para la conexión a la base de datos:

```
<!-- Datasource Oracle -->
    <dataSource id="DefaultDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/oracle">
         <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib"/>
         <properties.oracle URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.191.148.114:1521/ctra"/>
    </dataSource>

    <library id="OracleLib">
         <file name="/home/prueba/liberty/wlp/lib/ojdbc8.jar"/>
    </library>
```

El archivo de java lo he pasado a .ear y depositado en la carpeta app antes mencionada, en la terminal de linux ejecuto el archivo.ear (./WasPruebaEAR.ear) y me manda el error:

```
-bash: ./WasPruebaEAR.ear: cannot execute binary file
```

¿Alguien puede orientarme si es que estoy haciendo algo mal? ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm necesitas arrancar tu application server para ello vas a tu terminal y te colocas en la carpeta

```
/wlp/bin
```

Si miras lo que hay dentro de esa carpetas veras varios archivos

```
jgarnica@jgarnica-Aspire-E5-576G:~/wlp/bin$ ls -ltr
total 200
-rw-r--r-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  3945 Jun 25 04:58 serverSchemaGen.bat
-rwxr-xr-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  6792 Jun 25 04:58 serverSchemaGen
-rwxr-xr-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica 36503 Jun 25 04:58 server
-rw-r--r-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  3942 Jun 25 04:58 securityUtility.bat
-rwxr-xr-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  6789 Jun 25 04:58 securityUtility
-rw-r--r-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  3933 Jun 25 04:58 productInfo.bat
-rwxr-xr-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  6780 Jun 25 04:58 productInfo
-rw-r--r-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  3945 Jun 25 04:58 pluginUtility.bat
-rwxr-xr-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  6792 Jun 25 04:58 pluginUtility
-rw-r--r-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  3942 Jun 25 04:58 featureUtility.bat
-rwxr-xr-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  6789 Jun 25 04:58 featureUtility
-rw-r--r-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  3933 Jun 25 04:58 binaryLog.bat
-rwxr-xr-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  6780 Jun 25 04:58 binaryLog
-rw-r--r-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  3935 Jun 25 04:58 auditUtility.bat
-rwxr-xr-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  6782 Jun 25 04:58 auditUtility
-rw-r--r-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica 24187 Jun 25 05:06 server.bat
-rw-r--r-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  3623 Jun 25 05:07 configUtility.bat
-rwxr-xr-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  7020 Jun 25 05:07 configUtility
-rw-r--r-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  3626 Jun 25 05:10 featureManager.bat
-rwxr-xr-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  7023 Jun 25 05:10 featureManager
-rw-r--r-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  3618 Jun 25 05:11 collective.bat
-rwxr-xr-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  7015 Jun 25 05:11 collective
-rw-r--r-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  3626 Jun 25 05:14 installUtility.bat
-rwxr-xr-- 1 jgarnica jgarnica  7023 Jun 25 05:14 installUtility
drwxr-xr-x 3 jgarnica jgarnica  4096 Jun 25 07:06 jaxrs
drwxr-xr-x 3 jgarnica jgarnica  4096 Jun 25 07:06 tools
```

Tu necesitas ejecutar el archivo llamado **server** para arrancar tu WebSphere liberty,ya vi que has creado un servidor en tu application server y por lo tanto no estas usando el por default, el nombre de tu servidor es **nuevoservidor**

Entonces bastaria con ejecutar este comando desde la terminal

```
jgarnica@jgarnica-Aspire-E5-576G:~/wlp/bin$  ./server start nuevoservidor
```

y para detener servidor de aplicacion bastaria con  usar el parametro stop

```
jgarnica@jgarnica-Aspire-E5-576G:~/wlp/bin$  ./server stop nuevoservidor
```

PD: Desconozco si tengas bien configurado tu server.xml, antes de nada prueba corriendo un simple EAR usando unicamente un servlet despues vas probando y vas viendo como funciona todo.

En internet esta un [tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/es/websphere-liberty) donde explica el proceso mas a detalle pero en lugar de usar un EAR usa un archivo WAR, el proceso seria el mismo lo que cambia como tu ya sabes es que los EAR son proyectos que soportan multiples WAR.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder JGarnica, mi server ya está corriendo, mi problema es que no puedo hacer  que funcionbe mi EAR, lo que estoy intentando es correr una aplicación simple por consola de java con un "Hola Mundo" usando el System.out.println. Agradezco tusa comentarios.

Comment: Intenta correr un EAR el cual contenga un servlet, prueba y me dices como te fue, si tienes dificultades me avisas, estoy suponiendo que sabes como crear un EAR y compilarlo si no seria bueno aclarar eso desde el prinicipio para ayudarte de mejor forma.

Comment: Hola jgarnica, he hecho lo que comentas, el servidor está corriendo sin problemas, he convertido mi aplicación de JSF a .war, el nombre de la aplicacion es prueba, en el navegador le pongo localhost:9080/prueba y me despliega un error; "No se encuentra la raíz de contexto".